# Javascript len function

Tags: javascript, maxlength

I have a form verification that checks for a minimum length, which works fine.  However I also need to check for a max length.

I'm using the following code for an textarea field called "msg" to verify minimum lenth, which works fine:

```
 var msgval    = $("#msg").val();
 var msglen    = msgval.length;

if(msglen < 4) {
$("#msg").addClass("error");
}
else if(msglen >= 4){
$("#msg").removeClass("error");
}
```

This works fine, but if I add a similar verification for msglen > 250, it ignores the previous minimum length requirement when structured as such:

```
if(msglen < 4) {
$("#msg").addClass("error");
}
else if(msglen >= 4){
$("#msg").removeClass("error");
}
if(msglen > 250) {
$("#msg").addClass("error");
}
else if(msglen <= 250){
$("#msg").removeClass("error");
}
```

How can I combine the two arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the logical OR operator to test both conditions.

```
if (msglen < 4 || msglen > 250) {
    $("#msg").addClass("error");
} else {
    $("#msg").removeClass("error");
}
```

There's no need for an `else if` condition. If it's not less than 4 and not greater than 250, then you know you can remove the class.

---

Or a shorter version could be written like this:

```
$("#msg").toggleClass("error", msglen < 4 || msglen > 250);
```

A truthy value passed as the second argument will add the class. A falsey value will remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...I'm new to Javascript and should have checked the W3Schools tutorials before posting.  The argument operators are pretty self explanatory.

Comment: @PeterSusko - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) has a really good JS reference. If you ever wonder how a particular JS function works just google "thefunctionname mdn" and the first result is usually the MDN page on that function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it like this:

```
var msgval = $("#msg").val(),
    msglen = msgval.length,
    notValid = msgval.length < 4 || msgval.length > 250;
$('#msg').toggleClass('error', notValid);
```

or you could always set the `maxlength` property of the textbox to `250` and then you don't have to worry about the length exceeding 250 characters. :)

Comment: `maxlength` doesn't work on `<textarea>` elements, only on `<input>` elements (at least, not in all browsers).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(msglen < 4) {
  $("#msg").addClass("error");
}
```

Adds the class `error`

```
else if(msglen <= 250){
  $("#msg").removeClass("error");
}
```

Removes it a few lines later..

Why don't you just try this.

```
if(msglen < 4 || msglen > 250) {
    $("#msg").addClass("error");
}
```